# How to Avoid Copies When Doing Method Chaining in C++

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, method-chaining

I love to use method chaining to completely initialize objects and then store them in const variables. When analyzing the resulting code it turns out that this means the execution of many copy constructors. Therefore I have wondered whether C++ 11 move semantics might help optimizing method chaining.

Indeed I have been able to significantly speed up my code by adding overloads with ref qualifiers to my chain methods. Please consider this source code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#undef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
#undef ENABLE_MOVING

class Entity
{
public:

        Entity() :
                        data(0.0), text("Standard Text")
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Constructing entity." << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        Entity(const Entity& entity) :
                        data(entity.data), text(entity.text)
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Copying entity." << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        Entity(Entity&& entity) :
                        data(entity.data), text(std::move(entity.text))
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Moving entity." << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        ~Entity()
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Cleaning up entity." << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        double getData() const
        {
                return data;
        }

        const std::string& getText() const
        {
                return text;
        }

        void modify1()
        {
                data += 1.0;
                text += " 1";
        }

        Entity getModified1() const &
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Lvalue version of getModified1" << std::endl;
#endif

                Entity newEntity = *this;
                newEntity.modify1();

                return newEntity;
        }

#ifdef ENABLE_MOVING
        Entity getModified1() &&
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Rvalue version of getModified1" << std::endl;
#endif

                modify1();

                return std::move(*this);
        }
#endif

        void modify2()
        {
                data += 2.0;
                text += " 2";
        }

        Entity getModified2() const &
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Lvalue version of getModified2" << std::endl;
#endif

                Entity newEntity = *this;
                newEntity.modify2();

                return newEntity;
        }

#ifdef ENABLE_MOVING
        Entity getModified2() &&
        {
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                std::cout << "Rvalue version of getModified2" << std::endl;
#endif

                modify2();

                return std::move(*this);
        }
#endif

private:

        double data;
        std::string text;
};

int main()
{
        const int interationCount = 1000;

        {
            // Create a temporary entity, modify it and store it in a const variable
            // by taking use of method chaining.
            //
            // This approach is elegant to write and read, but it is slower than the
            // other approach.

                const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTimePoint =
                                std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

                for (int i = 0; i < interationCount; ++i)
                {
                        const Entity entity = Entity().getModified1().getModified1().getModified2().getModified2();

#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                        std::cout << "Entity has text " << entity.getText() << " and data "
                                        << entity.getData() << std::endl;
#endif
                }

                const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point stopTimePoint =
                                std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

                const std::chrono::duration<double> timeSpan = std::chrono::duration_cast<
                                std::chrono::duration<double>>(stopTimePoint - startTimePoint);

                std::cout << "Method chaining has taken " << timeSpan.count() << " seconds."
                                << std::endl;
        }

        {
            // Create an entity and modify it without method chaining. It cannot be
            // stored in a const variable.
            //
            // This approach is optimal from a performance point of view, but it is longish
            // and renders usage of a const variable impossible even if the entity
            // won't change after initialization.

                const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTimePoint =
                                std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

                for (int i = 0; i < interationCount; ++i)
                {
                        Entity entity;
                        entity.modify1();
                        entity.modify1();
                        entity.modify2();
                        entity.modify2();

#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
                        std::cout << "Entity has text " << entity.getText() << " and data "
                                        << entity.getData() << std::endl;
#endif
                }

                const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point stopTimePoint =
                                std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

                const std::chrono::duration<double> timeSpan = std::chrono::duration_cast<
                                std::chrono::duration<double>>(stopTimePoint - startTimePoint);

                std::cout << "Modification without method chaining has taken "
                                << timeSpan.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The version **without** method chaining is approximately **10** times faster here than the other one. As soon as I replace

```
#undef ENABLE_MOVING
```

by

```
#define ENABLE_MOVING
```

the version without method chaining remains only **1.5** times faster than the other one. So this is a great improvement.

Still I wonder whether I could optimize the code even more. When I switch to

```
#define DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
```

then I can see that there are new entities created for every call to getModified1() or getModified2(). The only advantage of move construction is that creation is cheaper. Is there a way to even prevent move construction and work on the original entity with method chaining?

Comment: But moving is semantically different from accessing from accessing const ref or copy, which in this context are the same i.e. preserve original object. It seems your proposal is not functionally the same. Moreover, depending on the implementation of `T&&` you might practically end up with a copy ctor for move.

Comment: Hmmm, could you elaborate on that, I do not get your point? The move constructor **really** moves the member field `data` which is the reason for the speed-up. Also I guess that creating a temporary instance and then calling the rvalue modification methods should give exactly the same result as creation a variable and calling the modification methods. And what do you mean with `T&&`?

Comment: I mean that your suggestion to replace copy with move doesn't sound good. It doesn't hold the same invariants. By `T&&` I meant `T(T&&)` i.e. move ctor. For simple types it is a copy, e.g. you can't really move an `int` or a `double`. Maybe I misunderstood which copies you want to avoid. There's lot's of them. Even in the `Entity getModified1() &&`. Any by introducing forced moves you can prevent compiler from allowed copy-elisions in favour of moves which are basically copies again, actually degrading performance. Maybe I misunderstand your problem. Sorry if that's it.

Comment: If you don't mind modifying the original entity, then just have `modify1` et al return `Entity&`, as in `return *this;`. Then you can do `const Entity entity = Entity().modify1().modify1().modify2().modify2();` and have only one move constructor called.

Comment: @luk32: I have added comments to the time measurement code to clarify my intention/problem. You are right that `return std::move(...)` might render copy elision impossible. But omitting `std::move` does not help here. If you enable debugging output (just use `#define DEBUGGING_OUTPUT`) and change `return std::move(*this);` to `return *this;` in the ref qualifier overloads (`Entity getModified*() &&)` then you see that the entity is copied at the end of every call to `getModified*() &&`. The performance also drops by a factor of 10 here.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: You are right, that works. Yet the method convention of the library I am working with is that the `modify*()` methods do not return anything. That's why I have tried to create a ref qualifier overload of `getModified*()`. Still with your input it seems as if I can improve my example...

Comment: If `getModified*() &&` returns a reference to the instance, then this reference is a lvalue. Therefore the lvalue overload of the next `getModified*()` method will be called which creates a copy. :-( But if I use std::move inbetween, then again the non-copying rvalue overload will be called. So an optimal call chain would be `const Entity entity = std::move(std::move(std::move(std::move(Entity().getModified1()).getModified1()).getModified2()).getModified2());` in this case. This is ugly of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Igor Tandetnik I guess that I can answer my question!

The modification methods have to be changed to return rvalue references:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_MOVING
Entity&& getModified1() &&
{
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
    std::cout << "Rvalue version of getModified1" << std::endl;
#endif

    modify1();

    return std::move(*this);
}
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_MOVING
Entity&& getModified2() &&
{
#ifdef DEBUGGING_OUTPUT
    std::cout << "Rvalue version of getModified2" << std::endl;
#endif

    modify2();

    return std::move(*this);
}
#endif
```

and the initialization has to happen like this:

```
const Entity entity = std::move(Entity().getModified1().getModified1().getModified2().getModified2());
```

Then the method chaining code is almost as efficient as the other code. The difference is one call to the move constructor and one additional destructor call for the temporary instance which is negligible.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would you explain why you have downvoted that answer? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be more idiomatic in C++ to use a [separate Builder class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Your problem is that you're using the class as itself and the builder class and you're committed to consts. This means every time you need to construct a new object every time, whether it's through a copy or move constructor that's slower than it needs to be.

Comment: @JMAA: I get your point. Still in this case the design seems rather fine to me. Think of `Entity` as a vector or point in space. Modifying it may be reverting the vector or translating the point. So the modified entity is a derivative of the original. It is much more natural to write `vector n = vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).normalized();` than using a separate vector builder class. But as I have already mentioned in my comment to luk32 the design stems from a third-party library. I cannot completely change the design, but perhaps improve the existing one.

Comment: In the case of `auto normal = vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).normalized()` then I'm confused why you would want the `vector` object to be immutable?

Comment: I would like to express that it is a non-changing, completely initialized constant. Very often it is necessary to compute a normal (of a triangle or tangential space) by computing cross products of spanning vectors and normalizing that cross product. Storing the normal as a const vector is preferrable for style reasons.

Comment: Right, so if it's just the final object that needs to be const, why not just do this: https://gist.github.com/yonni12/a9258ac72eb7b9c78c306bc07492ae0e i.e., return non-const references to the current object and just have the variable that's storing it be `const`

Comment: This has been the proposal of Igor Tandetnik which does not fit to the convention of the third-party library I am using. Still it is also a possibility to avoid copies when doing method chaining.

Comment: What exactly is the convention that this library is using? Or better still, what's the library?